# vb.net BindingSource.Find?

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

Anyway to use BS.Find with more than one column (like "ID",1 And "Name","Smith") ?

Answer (score 1):

Find will only work on primary keys, you can use Select or RowFilter for such a thing if your DataSource is DataTable

Comment: I don't find Select or RowFilter.

Comment: check type of DataSource property of your BindingSource